# How do I get all occurrences of hierarchical data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchy

In my **PostgreSQL** database (`version: 11.4`) I have table called `organizations`. This table has such structure:

```
| organization_id | organization_name | parent_organization_id | tree_organization_id | organization_rang |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------------------|-------------------|
| 1               | Alphabet          |                        | \1                   | 1                 |
| 2               | Google            | 1                      | \1\2                 | 2                 |
| 3               | Calico            | 1                      | \1\3                 | 2                 |
| 4               | Youtube           | 2                      | \1\2\4               | 3                 |
| 5               | Nest              | 2                      | \1\2\5               | 3                 |
| 6               | Facebook          |                        | \6                   | 1                 |
| 7               | Whatsapp          | 5                      | \6\7                 | 2                 |
| 8               | Instagram         | 5                      | \6\8                 | 2                 |
```

As you can see this table stores information about the hierarchical relationship between organizations. Let's say as input I have specific `organization_id` value. For example, it can be 4 (Youtube). I need to create a new column called `dependencies` where all the `tree_organization_id` that have the organization id would be stored. The data type of this new column must be `string array []text`.

In other words, I'm trying to get a similar result:

```
| organization_id | organization_name | parent_organization_id | tree_organization_id | organization_rang | dependencies              |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------------------|-------------------|---------------------------|
| 1               | Alphabet          |                        | \1                   | 1                 | ['\1', '\1\2', '\1\2\4' ] |
| 2               | Google            | 1                      | \1\2                 | 2                 | ['\1\2', '\1\2\4']        |
| 4               | Youtube           | 2                      | \1\2\4               | 3                 | ['\1\2\4']                |
```

I used such SQL request which find the parents of the organization, but how do I calculate the values in the `dependencies` column correctly?

```
with recursive hierarchy as (
    select
        organizations.organization_id,
        organizations.organization_name,
        organizations.parent_organization_id,
        organizations.tree_organization_id,
        organizations.organization_rang
    from
        organizations
    and
        organizations.organization_id in (4)
    union
    select
        a.organization_id,
        a.organization_name,
        a.organization_rang,
        a.parent_organization_id,
        a.tree_organization_id
    from
        organizations a
    inner join
        hierarchy b
    on
        a.organization_id = b.parent_organization_id
)
select
    hierarchy.organization_id,
    hierarchy.organization_name,
    hierarchy.parent_organization_id,
    hierarchy.tree_organization_id,
    hierarchy.organization_rang
from
    hierarchy
order by
    hierarchy.organization_rang;
```

Comment: 1/3 and 1/2/5 too the dependencies of Alphabet. Why that's not included?

Comment: @Santhosh parents should only consider what is sent as an incoming parameter. As I said before as input I send `4` (Youtube) and don't send `5` (Nest). For that's why `1/2/5` wouldn't bee in parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need a recursive CTE.  You can just match on the `tree` column:

```
select o.*,
       (select array_agg(o2.tree order by o2.rang)
        from organizations o2
        where o2.tree like (o.tree || '%')
       ) as dependencies
from organizations o;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d2cb6c09c1f7f8b5d85922b1b04a123) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that I changed the backslashes to forward slashes.  Backslashes are escape characters in strings, so they are finicky to work with.

Comment: I've adapted your code a bit with my own. I added your code to my recursion in the post. Also in my case, I can't change "\" to "/" as you. For that's why I changed your code to such statement `o2.tree LIKE CONCAT('%', '\', o.id, '%')` and it works as I want. Thank you for your help!